# mPDF error: Some data has already been output to browser

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm using mpdf to convert and display html to PDF

when i run it on my local pc/server i see the pdf, but when i run it on my site server i'm getting this error:

**mPDF error: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file**

```
$url = "http://".SITE_DOMAIN."/itinPage-printVer.php?itinID=".$_GET['itinID'];
$htmlStr = file_get_contents($url);

include('html2pdf/mpdf.php');
//ob_end_clean();

$mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8');

$mpdf->WriteHTML( $htmlStr);
$mpdf->Output();   
exit;
```

Could it be folder permissions?

Comment: Did you check to see if any output is sent to browser before writing PDF file? Any white spaces before `<?php` tags count as output as well.

Comment: yes. i checked . @Nima

Answer (score -1):

I addressed the problem successfully by changing the encoding of the .php file which contains the mpdf code from UTF-8 to ANSI!

Note: The file encoding does not affect the **contents** of your *$htmlStr* variable, so the output can be in any character set you wish (utf-8, etc).