# error using mpdf code to convert html to pdf

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm trying to use mpdf to convert and display html to PDF.
it's working fine on my local server. bu t when i upload it to remote server i'm getting this error:

> mPDF error: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file

Here is my code:

```
$url = "http://".SITE_DOMAIN."/itinPage-printVer.php?itinID=".$_GET['itinID'];
$htmlStr = file_get_contents($url);

include('html2pdf/mpdf.php');
//ob_end_clean();

$mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8');

$mpdf->WriteHTML( $htmlStr);
$mpdf->Output();   
exit;
```

Comment: Make sure you don't have spaces or empty lines before the `<?php` opening tag

Comment: Please don't repost https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46427975/mpdf-error-on-mpdf

Comment: Thank you @davey . it's helped...